# MySQL Update Inner Join Aliases

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to run this query:

```
UPDATE anothertable
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, 
                   LEAST(table1.from_price, table2.from_price, table3.from_price) AS cheapestPrice
              FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 v WHERE hotelid >= 1
                    UNION
                    SELECT * FROM table2 c WHERE hotelid >= 1
                    UNION
                    SELECT * FROM table3 k WHERE hotelid >= 1) AS temp      
           GROUP BY temp.hotelid, temp.country) AS i ON anothertable.id = i.hotelid 
                                                    AND anothertable.country = i.country
SET price = i.cheapestPrice, 
    op = i.to
```

However I cannot get the `LEAST` function to get access to a field called "from_price".

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Min instead of Least:

```
Update anothertable
    Join    (
            Select hotelid, country, to
                , Min(from_price) AS cheapestPrice
            From    (
                    Select hotelid, country, from_price, to
                    From table1 v 
                    Where hotelid >= 1
                    Union
                    Select hotelid, country, from_price, to
                    From table2 c 
                    Where hotelid >= 1
                    Union
                    Select hotelid, country, from_price, to
                    From table3 k 
                    Where hotelid >= 1
                    ) AS temp
            Group By temp.hotelid, temp.country, temp.to
            ) As i 
        On anothertable.id = i.hotelid 
            And anothertable.country = i.country
Set price = i.cheapestPrice
    , op = i.to
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in comments, I omitted the `to` column from the inner temp query. However, it occurs to me that it isn't clear how `to` should be included because you are using an awful feature of MySQL with respect to declaring the Group By columns. I'm assuming that you need to include `to` in the Group By however if that is not the case, you should be explicit about what aggregate function it should use on the `to` column.

Here's an alternate where I use Min on the `to` column:

```
Update anothertable
    Join    (
            Select temp.hotelid, temp.country
                , Min(temp.to) As to
                , Min(temp.from_price) AS cheapestPrice
            From    (
                    Select v.hotelid, v.country, v.from_price, v.to
                    From table1 v 
                    Where hotelid >= 1
                    Union
                    Select c.hotelid, c.country, c.from_price, c.to
                    From table2 c 
                    Where hotelid >= 1
                    Union
                    Select k.hotelid, k.country, k.from_price, k.to
                    From table3 k 
                    Where hotelid >= 1
                    ) AS temp
            Group By temp.hotelid, temp.country
            ) As i 
        On anothertable.id = i.hotelid 
            And anothertable.country = i.country
Set price = i.cheapestPrice
    , op = i.to
```

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - You mean other than the last line?

Comment: I mean your query will fail because of it. it refers to nothing

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi - OIC. Yeah, the OP is using that thrice damned feature in MySQL which lets you put something in the Select clause of a Group By query without requiring it be in the Group By or wrapped in an aggregate function.